# Use of single module multiple times

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created `Auth` and `Acl` modules using [zend-framework2](/questions/tagged/zend-framework2), And these two are working  good. Now I want to use these modules multiple times with different configuration.

Basically, I have two sections in my project -

1. User Section
2. Admin Section

And both have different `session` variables and different `database tables`.
I have `Auth` configuration file as following (*module.config.php*) -

```
return array(
    'auth' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'table' => 'user',
            'identity' => 'email',
            'credential' => 'password',
            'credential_treatment' => array(
                'class' => '\My\Common',
                'method' => 'encrypt'
            ),
            'status' => array(
                'is_enabled = true',
            ),
        ),
        'view' => array(
            'label' => array(
                'identity' => 'Email',
            ),
        ),
        'route' => array(
            'login' => 'home',
            'logout' => 'home',
        ),
        'whitelist' => array(
            'home',
        )
    ),

    ....
    ....
);
```

I want to use the same module for both `Admin` section and `User` section, But with different configuration settings, Like different `database tables` and `session variables`.

Is it possible to do so or I have to create different modules for different section?
Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an simple approach for your use case. I didn't test it, so expect some typos :)

I hope you get the basic idea. If not, let me know.

**config/autoload/auth.global.php**

```
return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'YourAuthNamespace\Config' => 'YourAuthNamespace\Service\ConfigServiceFactory',
            'YourAuthNamespace\AbstractAuthFactoryFactory' => 'YourAuthNamespace\Service\AbstractAuthFactoryFactory',
        ],
        'abstract_factories' => [
            'YourAuthNamespace\AbstractAuthFactoryFactory'
        ]
    ]
];
```

**src/YourAuth/Service/AbstractAuthFactoryFactory.php**

```
namespace YourAuth\Service;

class AbstractAuthFactoryFactory implements \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $key = $this->getConfigKeyFromServiceName($name);
        $config = $this->getConfig($serviceLocator);
        return array_key_exists($key, $config);
    }

    private function getConfig(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return $serviceLocator->get('YourAuthNamespace\Config');
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $key = $this->getConfigKeyFromServiceName($name);
        $config = $this->getConfig($serviceLocator);
        return new YourAuthClass($config[$key]);
    }

    private function getConfigKeyFromServiceName($name)
    {
        return preg_replace('#^YourAuthNamespace\Auth\#i', '', $name);
    }
}
```

**src/YourAuth/Service/ConfigServiceFactory.php**

```
namespace YourAuth\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class ConfigServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        return $config['yourauth'];
    }
}
```

**module/MyModuleA/config/module.config.php**

```
return [
    'yourauth' => [
        'ModuleA' => [ // 'ModuleA' is also the key used by the abstract factory
            'db' => [
                'table' => 'module_a_auth_table',
                // ...
            ],
            'session' => [
                'namespace' => 'module_a_session_namespace'
                // ...
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModuleA\Auth' => function ($sm) {
                    return $sm->get('YourAuthNamespace\Auth\ModuleA');
                }
        ),
    ),
];
```

**module/MyModuleA/src/AuthClient.php**

```
namespace MyModuleA;

class AuthClient implements \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    public function doSomethingWithAuth()
    {
        if ($this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyModuleA\Auth')->isAuthorized()) {
            // blah...
        }
    }
}
```